# How to download android emulator without using android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to download android emulator using Android Studio due to filtering.
So how can I download the emulator without Android Studio? Is there any website to do so?

Comment: You can use genymotion too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can download the android sdk without Android Studio

Check out the [downloads page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools).

Links to Android SDK latest version -

Windows - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip

Mac - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-6609375_latest.zip

Linux - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip

From [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505738/11626847)

Link to Emulator -

#### 32-bit

MacOS - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6855416.zip

Windows - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6855416.zip

Linux - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6855416.zip

#### 64-bit

MacOS - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip

Windows - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6885378.zip

Linux - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6885378.zip

> Note: These are the latest version of android emulators - 30.1.5

Comment: This worked for me. The only thing is that the links listed under "64-bit" are actually for version 30.2.2, while the links listed under "32-bit" are for version 30.1.5