# Android Emulator 30.4.5 not working on MacOS

Tags: android-emulator, macos-big-sur, android-studio-4.1

**System Info**

> MacOs Version - 11.3 Beta
>
> Android Studio Version - 4.1.2
>
> Android Emulator Version - 30.4.5
>
> Android HAXM Version - 7.5.1

**Error Stack**

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/rajaparikshit/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Failed to open the hax module
No accelerator found.
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
added library /Users/rajaparikshit/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library /Users/rajaparikshit/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
added library /Users/rajaparikshit/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
```

Android emulator version - 30.0.26 was running perfectly as expected. But after 30.4.5.0 update its not working.

I tried to search way to downgrade to 30.0.26 but I couldn't find one i.e. there is no any option in android studio manager also.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator) SO post. Google store all the emulators version in repository URL -  http://dl.google.com/android/repository/ but I didn't know the build version for 30.0.26 version so couldn't go this way.

**Update -**

Please follow the accepted answer below and do give upvote.

For newbies or if you get stuck at any point please follow the steps:

1. If you have uninstalled the latest version of emulator as its not working, then please install it again. (Because if we manually replace the emulator directory Android Studio is not able to recognise it and hence you won't able to create/run AVD from Android Studio)
2. Download the zip file from the URL mentioned in answer.
3. Copy(Not Move) the content to your original emulator directory.
4. Restart the android studio if needed.

Still this is just a workaround, actual issue with this new version is still there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the link for the emulator revision 30.0.26 https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip
(taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301909/1161027))

Download it and then copy over the installed emulator.

It won't work if you have files quarantine enabled; I did so I needed to remove quarantine recursively from downloaded files

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/dir
```

Then I can run the emulator by invoking:

```
emulator @device_name
```

It doesn't seem to be detected by AS, but works nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. How you get this URL of zip. I followed the answer you point but didn't get the URL.

Comment: its just there near the end of the post


```64-bit

MacOS - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip```

Answer (score 32):

Below is a temporary fix.

Error:

> cannot add library
> /Users//Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib:
> failed

It seems the dylib file doesn’t exists in the path specified in the error message.
However, the library exists in the path below:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
```

Symlink vaulkan lib to the path emulator is trying to load the library from:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64 ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64
```

Error 2:
Then I got an error related to code signing.

> HVF error: HV_ERROR
> qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument

Fix the code signing error:
Step 1:
Create the app.entitlements file for codesigning and add below content (source: https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/kdhgni/qemu_hvf_support_for_mac_os_x_bug_sur_hv_error/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

    <plist version="1.0"> <dict> <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key> <true/> </dict> </plist>
```

Step 2:
Perform codesign:

```
codesign -s - --entitlements ~/<path>/<to>/app.entitlements --force ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
```

Launch the emulator:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -gpu auto
```

Emulator should load without any errors. Hope this helped.

UPDATE: This issue no longer exists in the current version of the emulator. Please refer to @channe's comment to revert the change after upgrading AS/emulator.

Comment: The issue still exists on `30.5.6` and the this solution doesn't work in that version anymore: `ERROR: qt_setup.cpp:31: Qt library not found at /Users/example/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib`;;;`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5WebEngineWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/example/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Works! This should be the preferred answer

Comment: Initial issue seems to be fixed in 30.5.6. If you had used above fix, uninstall and reinstall back emulator from sdk manager. This will revert the changes.

Comment: @Dr.jacky - please follow channae's comment to revert the change.

Comment: Tried the @channae fix but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on a Mac. I was able to fix it be updating `Android Emulator to 30.6.5` from Android Studio -> Sdk Manager -> Android Sdk -> SDK Tools.
Also I had to install `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your android build tools to latest version avaialble in the studio, this will update your emulator binary and all libs(.dylibs). This is the correct fix..