# Android emulator version 30.5.4.0 mac os issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run android emulator, but instead of success I'm getting errors and lagged ui
Errors:

```
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library /Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Failed to open the hax module
No accelerator found.
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
added library /Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
```

I've already tried everything recommended steps from this post
[Android Emulator 30.4.5 not working on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455173/android-emulator-30-4-5-not-working-on-macos)
and from the other relative posts on stackoverflow and google search results, haven't succeed yet.

Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3

Comment: I just started to get this issue after upgrading to 11.3. Not sure why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288329/android-device-manager-fails-to-launch-after-updating-to-macos-big-sur-11-3/67288845

Answer (score 3):

For me worked a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66531164/9040566).

You have to download the emulator from the google repository https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip and replace the one you have already installed, with the downloaded one.

If you have file quarantine enabled, as I did, you have to remove it from downloaded files:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/dir
```

After this, your emulator should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like emulator update revision: 30.5.6 has solved this issue.