# Android Emulator closed because emuglConfig_init: blacklisted=0 ,GPI emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I try to run Android emulator and get this error, what i can do to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67290217/1732067

Comment: This is solution. Thanks for your help