# MACOS M1 Big Sur 11.3 - Issue running Android Studio 4.1.3 - Issue W/Nexus 6 API 28 Emulator

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

Everytime I try to start the emulator, I get the following error: AVD Manager "The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API_28 was killed"
I just bought this MAC today and am installing Flutter and Android for the first time.
Can anyone help a newbie?
Thanks

Comment: That was just asked yesterday (search for yourself, which you should already have done before asking) and may have to do with the latest Big Sur update. There's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Not only on M1 mac but also on Intel mac Android Emulators won’t work after update OS to 11.3.

For the present, you can avoid the issue by installing Canary build of AS. I cannot tell whether it will give us any side effects or not. As a temporal way out, it will work for me.

The URL of Android Studio Canary build is https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html .

After install it, you can still continue to use AS 4.1.3 as previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Check this, run in your console.
`./<your_android_sdk_path>/emulator/emulator -avd <Device name>`

If this error return, you need to copy vaulkan lib.

> cannot add library <your_android_sdk_path>/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed

See this for more specify solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67290217/1732067