# android emulator will not launch

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've read all the posts, regarding haxm, invalidate cache restart, software graphics, cold boot etc. I've reinstalled android studio and restarted a million times. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the sdk's and HAXM. I still get this error immediately when trying to launch the emulator. ALL emulators, tv, tablet, with google api without google api. x86, x86_64... same thing.

emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.4.0 (build_id 7453540) (CL:N/A)
Killed: 9

Nothing much to go off of.

Comment: The bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191799887.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android Emulator 30.4.5 not working on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455173/android-emulator-30-4-5-not-working-on-macos)

the fix was to download an older android emulator sdk and this literally solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem recently. It got solved when i updated the libraries. Try updating libraries and android studio.

Comment: updating the libraries actually caused this problem.