# Emulators won't run in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I can no longer run emulators. I have tried deleting and re-installing them, but clicking 'Run' produces the message "The emulator process for AVD  has terminated"
My project loads to real Android devices ok.

Suggestions please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio: "The emulator process for AVD Pixel\_2\_API\_30 has terminated." on MacBook Pro M1 (Apple Silicon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68312799/android-studio-the-emulator-process-for-avd-pixel-2-api-30-has-terminated-on)

Comment: @Cris The title states this is on Windows