# Why am I getting "This emulator process for avd has terminated" error?(Android studio)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-virtual-device

I tried opening an emulator on android studio but it kept giving me the same error.

I tried wiping data,

re-installing haxm many times

I also have a lot of free space in my disk (138gb)

How can I fix this?I couldn't even start programming in flutter :(

Comment: Do you have virtualization enabled in your bios?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes viztualization is enabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator The emulator process for AVD was killed. Windows Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317727/android-emulator-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-windows-intel)  also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68312799/10157127) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36841461/10157127)