# Android Emulator v31.2.9

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I'm trying to download android emulator v31.2.9 using sdk manager and its so slow it looks like it will never finish. I tried to look for the download link in android sdk and activity manager on macos and I can't find it. Can anyone help me with the direct link to android emulator v31.2.9 or any recent versions so I can download it directly. I am using a 64 bit os if that info is necessary. I tried to Google it and I could only find old versions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301741/how-to-download-android-emulator-without-using-android-studio but it's for an old version which won't work

Comment: what is your android studio version ?